# aligning the bottom of one "bigger" ul with the bottom of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a menu that opens to the right side of the the div that's clicked to activate it. However, I don't understand how I can do the positioning correctly. I would like the bottom of the last `li` (where I store the submenu options) to be even with the bottom of the div that activates the popout. However, giving is a negative margin

```
ul.dd{
  z-index:100;
  position:relative;
  margin-bottom:-30px;
  display:none;
}
```

isn't working out. How can I accomplish this

http://jsfiddle.net/mBPfG/1/

Thanks!

Comment: Will this be the only pull-out menu?  Will there be others with more than 3 list items?  If so this becomes more complicated in setting the margin-top

Comment: @JonHarding This will be the only one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your container div was preventing the hidden `<ul>` tag from floating to the right of the other. Also added a negative margin-top to adjust positioning.

I have updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mBPfG/4/).

I simply added:

```
.dd_container { width:600px; }

ul.dd{
  z-index:100;
  position:relative;
  margin-top:-60px;
  display:none;
}
```

However, I would suggest nesting your second `<ul>` within the first `<li>`.

Comment: Why would you suggest that nesting of `ul`s?

Comment: It is a standardized coding practice.  I updated the fiddle to account for aligning the bottom of the pop-out list.

Comment: Thanks Jon. This works well. Are negative margins a good practice, do you think?

Comment: No for something like this I would use absolute positioning so you aren't reliant upon the container div, working on the full solution now.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the `HTML` and `CSS` completely to have a more symatically correct answer.

```
<div id="dd_container" class="dd dd_container">
<ul class="dd_deploy">
    <li><a href="#_">more options --></a>
       <ul class="dd">
           <li><a href="#_">el1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#_">el2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#_">el3</a></li>   
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
<div class="cb"></div>
```

​​​​​​​​​​
Less markup is better

View the full [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jev4S/1/).

Comment: Aha. I see. Thank you. I guess I don't quite understand absolute positioning in that case. I thought that it referenced the absolute position of the page, yet when i put in a spacing div, http://jsfiddle.net/4D8fH/ , your solution still works...